# Why border-bottom is not working with v-bind in VUE?

Tags: css, vue.js, border

I want my input to have border-bottom when there is an error. Everything is working, but border-bottom not.

My input

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="label">First Name</label>
    <input class="input"  v-model="firstName"
     :class="{ 'errorin': $v.firstName.$error }"
                    placeholder="Enter first name..."
                    label="firstName"
                    @input="$v.firstName.$touch();delayTouch($v.firstName)"
                    @blur="$v.firstName.$touch"/>
   <transition
      enter-active-class="animated headShake"
    >
  <div class="show" v-if="$v.firstName.$dirty">
  <div class="error" v-if="!$v.firstName.required">Name is required</div>
  <div class="error" v-if="!$v.firstName.minLength">Name must have at least {{$v.firstName.$params.minLength.min}} letters.</div>
  <div class="error" v-if="!$v.firstName.alpha">Name can"t contain numbers</div>
  </div>
   </transition>
  </div>
```

input style

```
.input {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
        border: none;
        padding: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 5px gray;
        outline: none;
        position: relative;
        &:focus {
          border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa500;
        }
     }
```

and error style

```
.errorin{
    color: rgb(230, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  }
```

Comment: are you using SASS or CSS because & is a selector in SASS. In CSS it should be written separately  `.input:focus{border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa500;}`

Comment: I'm using SCSS.

Comment: Then it is fine syntax wise. Try adding `!important` like  `border-bottom: 2px solid red !important;`. Hope this works.

Comment: it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it worked. You can read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-apply-important-in-css/)